# Yarn (JS) commands failing with "Error: Could not find or load main class run"

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I'm working on an application that recently switched from `npm` to `yarn` and I am unable to run `package.json` scripts. Running a command with `yarn` results in the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class run`

Running the same commands with `npm` work fine. Example:

```
$ yarn run test
> Error: Could not find or load main class run
$ npm run test
> RUNS  test/jest/components/DataTable.test.js
> RUNS  test/jest/components/NavItem.test.js
> // etc
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've also got [Apache Yarn](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) installed and your system is using this yarn.

To confirm, run `yarn version` and you'll see something like the following:

```
hadoop 2.7.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 15ec7ccf46de536e6ce7a
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-06-29T06:04Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum fc0a1a23fc1868e4d5ee7fa2b28a58a
This command was run using 
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar
```

You'll need to resolve the conflict by aliasing one of the commands.

Comment: You could also just use "yarnpkg" instead of "yarn"...

Comment: Hi matt, what do you mean by aliasing? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Arjjun you can create an "alias" meaning an alternative name to call the program with. To create an alias in bash: `alias alias_name="command_to_run"`

Answer (score 5):

you can use yarnpkg equate to yarn

```
yarnpkg run test
```